# What is the difference between returning React.Fragment or an array?

Tags: reactjs, react-fragment

Is there any difference between returning `React.Fragment`

```
function Foo(){
    return (
        <>
            <div>hey</div>
            <div>hey</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Or return an array of components

```
function Bar(){
    return (
        [
            <div>hey</div>,
            <div>hey</div>,
        ]
    )
}
```

?

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bassi-uu2t2) for example.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov [This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bassi-uu2t2) says you are wrong. The second function does return a valid React Component.

Comment: "A React component can also return an array of elements:" https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov as of React v16+ that's no longer true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: <React.Fragment> vs array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236346/react-react-fragment-vs-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the React documentation: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

> Using array notation has some confusing differences from normal
>   JSX:
>
> Children in an array must be separated by commas.
>
> Children in an array must have a key to prevent React’s key warning.
>
> Strings must be wrapped in quotes.

So, if you wanted to use your second example you would need to give each item a `key` prop, and you have to make sure to comma seperate your list of items if you use an `array`.

So, `Fragments` just give a more familiar syntax vs arrays